# Tabs on android make the whole screen black

Tags: codenameone

IDE: Eclipse
Desktop OS: Mac

Device : Android 4.0.4

Hi,

last week i sent a new android build to the server, and it updated the jar files i have on my Mac, then i installed the app on LG android 4.0.4 device that i tested before, and was surprised to find some pages display all black.

After investigating a little, i discovered that when i use tabs on any form the form will be displayed black only on android, no problem on simulator nor IOS iPhone 6S.

I looked at the forum and i found similar problem happened a year ago , and the solution was to use "android.asyncPaint=false" temporarily . now this removed the black, but messed all the rendering while navigating between tabs.

So my question is why this happened now? the past three months i was developing and deploying on android without any problem. Did the newest update corrupt something?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Using the `android.asyncPaint` flag is discouraged as it will fallback into a relatively slow compatibility mode. We are currently investigating some regressions in some rendering optimizations that affect some devices and are in the process of deploying a solution for that.

Please let us know if the issues persist.

Comment: The issue is still there, Tabs contents are unreadable at all :

Comment: The issue is still there, Tabs contents are unreadable at all :

without the flag:
http://sendvid.com/l3l3nqnw

with the flag false:
http://sendvid.com/1z12900m

Comment: Can you add some details on how your app is styled to your question? Theme information etc.? Do you use gradients anywhere in the code/theme? Anything else?

Comment: Please also check out this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/IMt-UGNSwts/epejQI0tEQAJ and see if it works around the issue

Comment: I'm using the build it business theme, i modified some component colors, but nothing major. it works on simulator and IOS , and it worked fine on android on build generated last year in December and November.  This only happens on Tabs. I even inserted a tab in another form that was working fine and now with the Tabs in it, it just draws black!

Comment: I just tried Display.getInstance().setProperty("compatPaintMode", "true"); by putting it in initVars and it didn't fix the issue

Comment: I tried this: https://github.com/codenameone/TestCaseForTabsAndroidIssue it didn't reproduce the issue on my device. Direct APK link here: http://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?m=result&i=6288200100741120&b=4368c96a-69a5-4a51-9945-e96df8961d76&n=MyApplication-release.apk Does it happen on your device? If so this is probably an issue with older versions of Android and I'll need to check on one of our other devices.

Comment: FYI I just tried this on a galaxy nexus 4.4.4 cyanogen mod and wasn't able to reproduce.

Comment: I tried the github.com/codenameone/TestCaseForTabsAndroidIssue and worked fine until i added a button outside the tab , under it, and now its surrounded with black  [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/ao5b39.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Thanks, we're looking into this.

Comment: This should be solved with current builds, thanks for the effort on that!